# Como fazer uma classe que está dentro de outra herdar uma variável instanciada desta ultima em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes

Veja o seguinte script python:

```
class a:
        def __init__(self,n):
                self.n=n

        class b:
                def __init__(self):
                        ## o que botar aqui para receber a variável self.n ##
                def show(self):
                        return self.n
inst=a(3).b()
print(inst.show())
```

A classe "b" está dentro da classe "a". A classe "a" tem um argumento(além de self) e a classe "b" não tem nenhum. Gostaria de saber como faço para a classe "b" herdar a variável "self.n" da classe "a" para que ela possa ser usada no método "show". O objetivo é que este script mostre o número 3.

Comment: Qual o objetivo de ter uma inner class no seu caso? Explicando o problema pode ser que haja uma outra forma .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No Python é preciso criar explicitamente o acesso

Você deve acessar a classe interna através de uma função na classe externa.

Tente dessa forma:

```
class externa(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n        

    def getInterna(self):
        return self.interna(self)

    class interna(object):
        def __init__ (self, pai):
            self.pai = pai

        def show(self):
            return self.pai.n

inst = externa(3).getInterna()

print(inst.show())
```

Comment: Entendi o que você colocou, mas não foi isso que eu pedi. Meu objetivo não é criar um código que mostre 3. É fazer a classe interna receber uma variável da externa. Nesse seu exemplo, você nem usou a classe interna. Ela poderia ser deletada que não haveria diferença na saída de dados. O script que eu mostrei é um exemplo de como quero resolver meu problema, meu verdadeiro script é muito grande e ficaria difícil de entender se eu fosse botá-lo todo. Por isso simplifiquei nesse. @pagotti

Comment: Essa resposta está correta. O que voce esta tentando fazer é que não está.

Comment: @Benedito se você perceber na penúltima instrução ele pega a instância da classe interna chamando `getInterna()`.

Comment: Realmente estava correto. Não sei o que eu tinha olhado. Obg.

Answer (score 3):

Sem entender o seu problema é uma questão complicada de responder.
A pergunta não faz nem muito sentido.

Mas vamos lá - por que você quer declarar uma classe interna à outra?
A declaração da classe em si não cria objetos dessa classe - a única diferença é que para se instanciar a classe `b`, no exemplo que você dá, é necessário se digitar `a.b()` - nesse caso o Python busca dentro da *classe* `a` o atributo  `b  verifica que é "chamável" - como não é uma função ordinária, essa chamada não ganha automaticamente o parâmetro`self` que é colocado em métodos.

Ou seja, em :

```
class a:
    def b(self):
        ...
```

Quando você chama `b` o próprio Python coloca o atributo `self` ali.

No seu exemplo, a classe `a.b` é instanciada normalmente e não vai saber nada sobre a classe `a` - muito menos sobre instâncias especificas da mesma.

A forma de se passar essa referência é instanciar a classe em um método - que pode ser usado como um "factory" dos objetos `a.b`- isso fica praticamente igual está na outra resposta:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
         ...
    def b_factory(self):
         return self.__class__.b(self)

    class b:
         def __init__(self, instancia_pai):
               self.instancia_pai = instancia_pai
               print(self.instanca_pai.n)
```

Você observou no comentário que "tanto faz a classa b estar dentro de `a`" EXATAMENTE - porque para qualquer efeito prático, tanto faz mesmo. 
Se `a` precisar ter instâncias de `b` atreladas a cada instância, pode fazer isso em seu próprio `__init__` - 
E a sintaxe do Python permite que você declare classes uma dentro da outra, e use essas classes como `Namespaces` para atributos de classe - mas na hora que você quer começar a criar instâncias dessas classes, e ter referências a instâncias - (você quer o atributo `self.n` de uma instância de `a`), tem que passar essas instâncias como parâmetros para os métodos.

## A resposta que você quer

Apesar de não fazer sentido o que você quer fazer, Python tem um mecanismo de atributos dinâmicos chamado de `descriptors`, que pode ser usado para fazer o que quer você esteja precisando, mas do jeito "correto". Internamente é o mecanismo que o Python usa para acrescentar o parâmetro `self` aos métodos, e é mais comum que seja usado em código de usuários com o *decorator* `property` do Python.

É o seguinte: toda vez que o Python vai recuperar um atributo de uma classe, ele verifica se aquele atributo existe primeiro na classe (e não primeiro na instância)  - se sim, ele verifica se o atributo tem o método especial `__get__`. Se tiver, em vez de continuar a busca, o Python chama esse método `__get__` passando a instância e a classe onde o atributo foi buscado como parâmetros.

Só que aí que a coisa fica diferente. O método  `__get__` tem que ser da classe do atributo recuperado. Se o próprio atributo for a classe, ele não funciona. Ou seja: para usar `descriptors` as classes tem em seu corpo instâncias de classes que tem o método `__get__` e não as próprias classes. Você pode até fazer a declaração aninhada mas, para funcionar, você tem que ter uma instância da classe aninhada, não a própria classe no corpo de `a`:

Em resumo, seu código pode ser escrito assim:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.n=n

    class b:
        def __init__(self):
            ...

        def show(self):
            return self.instance.n

        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
             self.instance = instance
  c = b()
```

E com esse código você pode fazer:
`a(5).c.show()`
Mas não `a(5).b.show()` (e sim, perceba que não faz a menor diferença a declaração de  `b` estar dentro de `a` - e sim, se eu tivesse chamado a instância `c` de `b` daria na mesma - só que você não teria mais acesso a classe `b`, apenas a uma única instância criada dela).

Não sei direito o que você quer fazer com classes aninhadas - mas veja a documentação sobre `descriptors`, e provavelmente vai ver que eles é que pode fazer o que você está querendo fazer com as classes aninhadas.

A documentação oficial do Python sobre `descriptors` é extremamente concisa e está toda aqui: https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors

E em geral, a classe de *descriptors* que vem pronta, `property`, já faz tudo que é necessário: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property