# Classe dentro de classe, é possível? (Python)

Tags: python, classes

Posso incluir uma classe dentro de outra classe (**Pai e filha rsrs**)?
Motivo da pergunta?
Simples, no Django eu vi algo parecido com isso

```
class Form(...):
  class Meta:
    (code)
```

Ok, pesquisei... [Encontrei isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179657/como-fazer-uma-classe-que-est%C3%A1-dentro-de-outra-herdar-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-instanciada-d), aqui mesmo no SOPT

Mas como sou iniciante em Python, ficou a dúvida:

Isso é correto?

Comment: Sobre sua última pergunta: [Quando devo usar `__init__` em funções dentro de classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109013/5878) / [Qual a diferença entre classes inicializadas com (e sem) `__init___`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330250/5878) / [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/5878) / [Qual é a diferença entre `__init__` e `__new__`?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177882/5878) / [Onde fica o construtor da classe em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109813/5878)

Comment: Eu até recomendaria retirar essa dúvida da pergunta, pelo menos por ora, para focarmos na questão de se usar classe dentro de classe. Se, mesmo após as perguntas citadas, restar alguma dúvida, pode criar uma nova focada no método `__init__`. O que acha?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, retirei a pergunta. Valeu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível,  mas tem utilidade limitada: só serve quando você quer usar a classe interna como um "namespace", e nunca vai querer criar uma instância dela.

Só é correto. por exemplo, quando você quer deixar alguns parâmetros para a classe,
mas não quer deixar esses parâmetros direto como atributos da classe - 
pra evitar confusão de nomes.

Ou seja, é exatamente o que o Django faz em seus "models": tem um monte de parâmetros que ele precisa anotar em uma classe de model - mas se ficasse tudo direto embaixo da classe, nenhum campo do model ia poder ter o mesmo nome que nenhum desses atributos.

Por exemplo:

```py
In [137]:  
     ...: class MinhaClasse: 
     ...:     a = 0 
     ...:     class Interna: 
     ...:        a = 5 
     ...:                                                                                                                                              

In [138]: obj = MinhaClasse                                                                                                                            

In [139]: obj.a                                                                                                                                        
Out[139]: 0

In [140]: obj.Interna.a                                                                                                                                
Out[140]: 5
```

No entanto, você não deve fazer isso se tiver intenção de instanciar a classe `Interna`  ou se quiser que cada instância de `MinhaClasse`  tenha uma instancia da classe `Interna`. Ou seja: para o uso *normal* de classes **não se deve usar classes dentro de classes**.

Se você quer que por exemplo, uma classe `Veiculo` tenha uma instância de `Motor` dentro, o correto é criar as duas classes separadas, e na inicialização de `Veiculo` criar a instância de `Motor` para aquele veiculo:

```
In [141]: class Motor: 
     ...:     pass 
     ...:                                                                                                                                              

In [142]: class Veiculo: 
     ...:     def __init__(self): 
     ...:         self.motor = Motor() 
     ...:                                                                                                                                              

In [143]: meu_carro = Veiculo()                                                                                                                        

In [144]: meu_carro.motor                                                                                                                              
Out[144]: <__main__.Motor at 0x7f1dc57ab400>
```

Eu coloco esse exemplo aqui, por que já vi gente achando que ao definir uma classe dentro de outra, por "mágica" quando você cria uma instância da classe de fora, o Python iria criar uma instância da classe de dentro - isso não acontece.

Comment: Sanou minha dúvida, e pela sua explicação, achei melhor fazer Class 1, Class 2, uma em baixo da outra. Achava que ficava mais organizado uma dentro da outra, mas: "...o correto é criar as duas classes separadas, e na inicialização de Veiculo criar a instância de Motor...", Vlw @jsbueno.